# Speed typing automation in Python

Tags: python, selenium

This is my code to automate fast typing in Typeracer

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


class TyperaceBot:
    def __init__(self):
        # Opening the Typeracer website
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://play.typeracer.com/")
        time.sleep(5)

        # Clicking on the "Enter a typing race"
        enter_race = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a")
        enter_race.click()
        time.sleep(7)

        # Get the text from the website
        type_text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div").text
        print(type_text)

        # Wait till the countdown is zero and start typing the text in the answer box
        while True:
            countdown_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/div[6]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/span").text
            if countdown_box == ":00":
                time.sleep(0.5)
                break

        # Start typing in the answer box
        answer_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input")
        answer_box.click()
        answer_box.send_keys(type_text)
        for letter in type_text:
            answer_box.send_keys(letter)
            delay = 9 / 1000
            time.sleep(delay)


my_typing_bot = TyperaceBot()
```

My problem is that when this block of code is executed:

```
 for letter in type_text:
                answer_box.send_keys(letter)
                delay = 9 / 1000
                time.sleep(delay)
```

The text will appear in the text box of the website but the full text is not typed. It stops in the middle and I have to do this again. [image]

The complete text is not typed but only a part of it is written. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does it work if you use a longer delay?

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with the string. I am getting the paragraph content. The problem arises when the letters are entered in the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct way of doing it. The site algorithm expects from you to press space, so when you find a "space" you need to press it. In your code I've also changed the XPath with CSS selectors - it's more efficient. Also - now the time is handled and the typing is done very fast, played a little bit myself with that.
And the site expects to type letters not words, that's why I've changed the way of doing it.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class TyperaceBot:
    def __init__(self):
        # Opening the Typeracer website
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver.get("https://play.typeracer.com/")
        time.sleep(2)
        
        # Clicking on the "Enter a typing race"
        enter_race = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Enter a typing race']")
        enter_race.click()

        # Wait till the countdown is zero and start typing the text in the answer box
        time.sleep(5)
        while True:
            try:
                countdown_box = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='trafficLight']")
                print('found')
                if countdown_box.is_displayed():
                   time.sleep(1)
            except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
                print('pop-up is gone')
                break

        # Get the text from the website
        full_text = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            "table[class='gameView'] table[class='inputPanel'] tbody tr:nth-child(1) tbody tr div").text
        print(full_text)

        # Start typing in the answer box
        answer_box = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table[class='gameView'] table[class='inputPanel'] input[class='txtInput']")
        answer_box.click()
        print('click')
        for words in full_text:
            for letter in words:
                if (letter == ""):
                    answer_box.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
                    time.sleep(0.02)
                    print("space")
                else:
                    answer_box.send_keys(letter)
                    time.sleep(0.02)
                    print(letter)

my_typing_bot = TyperaceBot()
```

Comment: Thanks! The changes you made have definitely helped me a lot! But I had to remove the agree button clause because I was getting an error. Thanks again!

Comment: if this works, can you accept as correct? The agree button annoyed me, what error it shows? maybe the element isn't ready for click

Comment: I didn't get the agree button at all. The script couldn't find it so I had to delete that line

Comment: updated the code without the agree button, I think now is ready for accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thanks a lot, dude! I uploaded this to my GitHub and mentioned you too. You have helped me a lot. I have been stuck at this for a week.
https://github.com/praneethravuri/Typeracer-Automation

Comment: share the git url, but don't forget to accept the answer - so the SO can clear it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is not in the statement you mentioned.

```
answer_box.send_keys(type_text) ## delete this line and try to run
for letter in type_text:
    answer_box.send_keys(letter)
    delay = 9 / 1000
    time.sleep(delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code your issue was setting up the for loop incorrectly.

```
        # Start typing in the answer box
        answer_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input")
        delay = 9 / 1000
        for letter in type_text:
            answer_box.send_keys(letter)
            time.sleep(delay)
```